# Redirect with URL fragment with Play framework 2

Tags: scala, redirect, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I add an URL fragment (`#xyz`) to a link created by the `Redirect` method?

I want something like this:

```
Redirect(routes.Comment.get(itemId) + "#xyz")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the url form the route using .url (which contains a relative url). Redirect needs two parameters to accept a string to redirect to

so, `Redirect(routes.Comment.get(itemId).url + "#xyz", SEE_OTHER)` should work

Edited when I realized Redirect() takes a Call and not a string

Answer (score 2):

With Play Framework 2.4 is possible do this:

```
Redirect(routes.Comment.get(itemId).withFragment("#xyz").toString)
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was surprised `toString` is needed, it compiles without, but doesn't pass the fragment then.

Comment: `withFragment()` automatically adds a pound sign, so you can omit it.

For posterity, `withFragment()` was added by PR 4152: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4152